# trying to get a new column with yes,no value

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables:

1. shortlisted folders with columns (folderid,foldername,userid)
2. shortlisted users with column(folderid, shortlisteduserid)
   they are linked with folderid

i am using following query to get list of folders created by userid 50 and count that 50 has shortlisted how many users in each folder

```
select a.folderid,a.foldername,count(b.ShortlistedUserId) as [count]
from tblshortlistfolders a left outer join tblshortlistedusers b on a.folderid=b.folderid 
where a.userid = 50
group by a.folderid,a.foldername
```

now i want to add one more column to this result whose values for each row will be as follow

1. if the folderid contains 49 in tblshortlistedusers userid then
   value = 'yes'
2. if the folderid do not contains 49 in tblshortlistedusers userid
   then value = 'no'

but when i somehow apply this condition , the column count do not show correct value and the result do not get grouped by folders. multiple rows are shown in result for same folder.

how to get the required table result (folderid, foldername, totalcount, 'newcolumn')

Answer (score 1):

Would help if you showed your query that you tried. I think this might do what you want: (from memory)

```
select a.folderid,a.foldername,count(b.ShortlistedUserId) as [count]
,case when count(case when b.ShortlistedUserId=49 then 1 else null end)>0 then 'Yes' else 'No' end as [NewColumn]
from tblshortlistfolders a left outer join tblshortlistedusers b on a.folderid=b.folderid 
where a.userid = 50
group by a.folderid,a.foldername
```

**EDIT:**
Maybe I am misunderstanding your data. Here is a full example with some sample data:

```
use tinker -- or whatever test db you have.

CREATE TABLE tblshortlistfolders (
 folderid     INT NOT NULL primary key
,foldername   NVARCHAR(255)
,userid       INT NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE tblshortlistedusers (
 folderid            INT NOT NULL
,shortlisteduserid   INT NOT null
,constraint fk_tblshortlistedusers_folderid foreign key (folderid) references [dbo].[tblshortlistfolders]
);

INSERT INTO tblshortlistfolders VALUES ( 100 , 'one'   ,  1); -- created by user 1
INSERT INTO tblshortlistfolders VALUES ( 200 , 'two'   , 50); -- created by user 50
INSERT INTO tblshortlistfolders VALUES ( 300 , 'three' , 50); -- created by user 50
INSERT INTO tblshortlistfolders VALUES ( 400 , 'four'  , 49); -- created by user 49

INSERT INTO tblshortlistedusers VALUES ( 100,  1); -- shortlisted by 50
INSERT INTO tblshortlistedusers VALUES ( 100, 50); -- shortlisted by 01 too
INSERT INTO tblshortlistedusers VALUES ( 200, 50); -- shortlisted by 50
INSERT INTO tblshortlistedusers VALUES ( 200, 49); -- shortlisted by 49 too
INSERT INTO tblshortlistedusers VALUES ( 300, 50); -- shortlisted by 50
INSERT INTO tblshortlistedusers VALUES ( 300, 50); -- shortlisted by  1 too

SELECT a.folderid,a.foldername,COUNT(b.ShortlistedUserId) AS [COUNT]
,CASE WHEN COUNT(CASE WHEN b.ShortlistedUserId=49 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END)>0 THEN 'Yes' ELSE 'No' END AS [NewColumn]
FROM tblshortlistfolders a LEFT OUTER JOIN tblshortlistedusers b ON a.folderid=b.folderid 
WHERE a.userid = 50
GROUP BY a.folderid,a.foldername
```

This does what I understood form your question. maybe you can give an example of what you want?

Comment: even i am doing it like this, but the problem is that the count of the users in that folder is always zero which do not contains user 49.. nd the folder which contains userid 49 shows the correct count of the total users contained in it.. :(

Comment: Please review the sample I gave and let us know how this differs from what you are expecting?

Answer (score 0):

```
select 
    a.folderid,
    a.foldername,
    count(b.ShortlistedUserId) as [count],
    case when b.userid = 49 then 'yes' else 'no' end as [newcolumn]
from 
    tblshortlistfolders a 
    left outer join tblshortlistedusers b on a.folderid=b.folderid 
where a.userid = 50
group by a.folderid,a.foldername
```

Comment: table b donot has userid column and when i replace it with ShortlistedUserId, and also in groupby clause it gives single row for single user i.e. multiple rows for single folder :(